# Connector name/where to buy

Tags: connector, wiring

I find lately that this connector type would come in very useful for the projects I make. but I have no idea what the connector is called, could someone please point me in the direction of its name, maybe I can buy a strip to cut to size?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the Harwin M20-106 crimp housings I use with M20-1180046 crimp socket inserts and 0.1" single-in-line headers:

http://uk.farnell.com/harwin/m20-1060800/crimp-housing-8way/dp/865667

They are available in various lengths, I buy the longer ones and cut them to size. I use a cheap crimp tool intended for use with Molex terminals with the sockets; it requires some care, but works quite well.

Comment: you forgot to say what they are an such, it seems you just gave a link that if(when is more accurate for the internet) it breaks the answer has 0 value, can you please bring over the key information to your post?

Comment: This one is long and can be cut down, it mentioned connector materials such as bronze and gold, does this mean it comes with the crimps? Also I noticed you have to order 10 minimum :S

Comment: I mentioned the crimp sockets you use with them.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a standard type socket(or plug/receptacle) for a 2.54mm pitch header.
Names like Molex, Tyco (now might be TE I think), Harwin, 3M, Samtec make various types of these.
If you go to Mouser, Digikey, Farnell and type header into the search you will get lots of options.
Places like Sparkfun and Adafruit will almost certainly have some options also.
You will need crimp contacts and a crimp tool to fit the wires (also sold at the above places).

Comment: Because I don't have a crimping tool, I use a similar type of connector which normally is supposed to be mounted on pcbs. I solder them to a ribbon cable and sescure the solder points with hot glue: The process takes some time and the result looks quite ugly, but can be accepted for hobby projects IMO.

Comment: You might be able to use floppy or IDE ribbon connectors for this job. Might need some work to fit it to the job, but the connector itself is designed to cut into the ribbon cable.

Answer (score 0):

These are called Pin Headers, though that term is usually meant for the metal pins the pictured socket connects to.